# UK to Schengen to USA, when to be at the airport?

Tags: schengen, transit

this is mostly a non-issue but anyway.

I will by flying from BHX to ORD via AMS next week. I have ample layover time in AMS but my flight from BHX departs at 6:10am. Both flights are booked on the same ticket, both with KLM. I will travel only with carry-on luggage and will check in online if possible.

How early do I need to be at BHX for the "non-transatlantic" leg? I'm asking as I'm not sure when the screening/pre-immigration for the US will take place, at AMS or at BHX. I cannot see how it could possibly happen at BHX, but you never know.

If anyone has any experience with this kind of itinerary (UK-Schengen-US), kindly let me know. I don't fancy getting to the airport at 3 o'clock, but of course I also don't want to be denied boarding because I arrived 60 minutes before departure. Any help is appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How early do I need to be at BHX for the "non-transatlantic" leg?

I would do 45 minutes. 30 might be enough but that's cutting it extremely close.

> I'm asking as I'm not sure when the screening/pre-immigration for the US will take place, at AMS or at BHX. I cannot see how it could possibly happen at BHX, but you never know.

You are right: it doesn't. If you have a documentation problem, KLM will refuse to check you in and tell you to see an agent at the airport for documentation check so you will know (you have no idea how many of these error messages I got for eight long years...). The US extra fun always happens as you enter the gate just before you board to a plane to the USA.

Comment: No USA prescreening in AMS yet, plans have been posponed I am told, so just normal check-in, security and boarding, all immigration things happen in the USA.

Comment: I know there's no preclearance at AMS but occassionally(?) there's extra screening going on before boarding US bound planes.

Comment: @Willeke I don't know how it is now, but it used to be that there was extra security and an additional document check for US-bound flights that happened at the gate.

Comment: There might well be extra checking at the gate, I have not flown to the USA in quite a while. But what I am talking about is what Ireland and Canada among others have, that you get the 'entering the USA' checks before getting on the flight. There were plans for that, but those have been posponed.